# Case statement not working in bash, conditions not apply

Tags: bash

Case statement not working. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>(empty string) not make script exit, other cases not working too. No one `exit 1` commands run when it should, all cases fails when I type text specially for it.

I find out what case works, but `exit 1` statement in it not exits the script. How to exit script in that place correctly?

```
#!/bin/bash
...
get_virtual_host() {
    if [ -t 0 ]; then
        read -p "Create virtualhost (= Folder name,case sensitive)" -r host
    else
        # same as 'read' but for GUI
        host=$(zenity --forms --add-entry=Name --text='Create virtualhost (= Folder name,case sensitive)')
    fi
    case "$host" in
        "")            notify_user "Bad input: empty" ;      exit 1 ;;
        *"*"*)         notify_user "Bad input: wildcard" ;   exit 1 ;;
        *[[:space:]]*) notify_user "Bad input: whitespace" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    echo "$host"
}

host=$(get_virtual_host)
```

Addition to clarify:

```
notify_user () {
    echo "$1" >&2
    [ -t 0 ] || if type -p notify-send >/dev/null; then notify-send "$1"; else xmessage -buttons Ok:0 -nearmouse "$1" -timeout 10; fi
}
```

Comment: Your output is stored in `host` variable at the end of command-substitution `$(..)`, did you do an `echo "$host"` after it

Comment: Sure, I use that variable. It works when some text typed in input. However no one of `exit 1` works when it should.

Comment: Does `$host` end up containing a control character by any chance? Can you  `cat -v <<<"$host"` for debugging?

Comment: I did. No control characters. Problem is elsewhere. I found output of notify_user in stderr, but `exit 1` followed it wan't do what I want - exit script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is in fact written correctly. It's how it's called that's the problem.

```
host=$(get_virtual_host)
```

When you capture a command's output the command runs in a subshell. Exiting the subshell doesn't directly cause the parent shell to exit; the parent shell needs to check the subshell's exit status.

```
host=$(get_virtual_host) || exit
```

This will exit the parent if `get_virtual_host` fails. A bare `exit` without an explicit exit code forwards the existing value of `$?`.